# PostgreSQL multiple counts query performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sqlperformance

I'm writing a query in postgres to select the posts with more comments.

The following works but I'm wondering if it could become a performance problem with many posts.

**Query**:

```
SELECT 
    po.*, 
    (SELECT count(id) FROM comments WHERE post_id = po.id) AS comments_count
    FROM posts AS po
    ORDER BY comments_count DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

**Result**:

```
id   title  body  comments_count
2    Foo    Bar   5
1    Click  Bait  4
```

Is there something I can do to improve this query performance or is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join instead of correlated subquery. Assuming id is PK in posts table:

```
select p.*,
    count(c.id) as comments_count
from posts p join comments c on p.id = c.post_id
group by p.id
order by comments_count desc limit 10;
```

or

```
select p.*,
    c.comments_count
from posts p
join (
    select post_id,
        count(id) as comments_count
    from comments
    order by comments_count desc LIMIT 10
    ) c on p.id = c.post_id;
```

Comment: In the second example i get this error:

`argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer`

Comment: @pietrovismara - That was a typo. Updated the answer. please try now

Comment: Anyway, comparing the `EXPLAIN` result for your first query and mine, yours looks much better. Is this because using join the count is done only on matching comments instead of all?

Comment: It's because of the correlated subquery. It's complexity is `O(n^2)`.